# How to set IBM Websphere 8 to serve web applications on different ports?

Tags: web-applications, websphere, port

I need to deploy two applications as WAR files on Websphere.
Both of them will require only HTTPS access.

Is it possible to run these two web applications on separate ports on same Websphere instance?

For example, will it be possible to access two applications like this:

```
https://192.101.1.101:7070/WebApplication1/
```

and

```
https://192.101.1.101:7080/WebApplication2/
```

(Same IP, same protocol(https), different ports)

Comment: Not sure what exactly you mean by "instance". Which edition do you have installed? One server can listen on only one port for https (and another one for http). But you can create two different servers. You can see if you can create multiple servers by going to the admin console.

Comment: There is a New option only above the Web servers list. Above the Application servers list there is no New option.

Comment: That means you are running a standalone server. I don't think you can make one server listen on multiple ports for the same protocol.

Comment: The console allows me to create new virtual host and add a port number for the virtual host. What is the use of this host name and port if server is not listening on that port?

Comment: Go to `Application servers > your_server > Ports`. `WC_defaulthost` and `WC_defaulthost_secure` have the ports where the web container listens for HTTP and HTTPS respenctively.

Comment: Virtual host is not going to help? As far as understanding virtual hosts you can read this - http://websphereinterviewquestions.blogspot.com/2009/12/what-is-virtual-host-and-how-to.html.

Comment: I went through the post. It looks like WAS listens only on single port for a single protocol. Mapping a virtual host with some other port is not working. Is there any part missing? If WAS is listening only on 7080, then is there any way to route 7081 to it?

Comment: Why are you using a standalone server? Easiest would be start the node and create another server.

Comment: Is that possible? That would be great. Which tool do I use for that? Not through console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IBM WAS Standalone server allows creation of multiple profiles on same server using Profile Management Tool. It is almost like there are two IBM installations on the same server.

There are two Windows processes one for each profile. And the entire set of ports are incremented automatically making them as two different app server instances. Its easy to manage both using the Profile management tool. Also, they have separate consoles where settings can be adjusted.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, (on WebSphere Application Server V8.5.5) and here is an example of how to do it:

```
<httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint" host="*" httpPort="9080" />
<httpEndpoint id="localHostOnly" host="localhost" httpPort="9081" />

<virtualHost id="alice">
     <hostAlias>your_host_name:9080</hostAlias>
</virtualHost>

<virtualHost id="bob">
     <hostAlias>localhost:9081</hostAlias>
</virtualHost>

<application id="App1" location="myApp.ear" name="App1"
type="ear"/>
<application id="App2" location="myApp2.war" name="App2"
type="war"/>
```

From IBM:

> The defaultHttpEndpoint exposes all interfaces on port 9080, the http
>   endpoint with id="localHostOnly" specifies host="localhost", meaning
>   that port 9081 is only exposed on the localhost interface.
>
> If App1 has a WAR file with an ibm-web.bnd.xml file specifying
>   `<virtual-host name="alice"/>` then  this application can only be
>   accessed at your_host_name:9080/app1_context_root.
>
> If App2 (which is a WAR) has an ibm-web-bnd.xml file specifying
>   `<virtual-host name="bob"/>` then this application can only be accessed
>   at localhost:9081/app2_context_root.
>
> If a third application were deployed which specified no specific
>   virtual host, that application in this configuration would be
>   available on all interfaces of the defaultHttpEndpoint on port 9080,
>   excluding your_host_name:9080 - for example it could be accessed on
>   localhost:9080/app3_context_root.

For more info see the closing text on this APAR:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM97514

Comment: Both are on intranet. Both need to be exposed with IP:port format. In that case, how will i change the your_host_name

Comment: You just replace it with the IP.

Comment: Could you please explain what to configure in ibm-web.bnd.xml ? Looks like something needs to be done there to make sure application can only be accessed using a particular port..

Comment: @Teddy: Are you using the Liberty Profile? I don't think so. Also, how do you start your WAS?

Comment: So for each app with an ibm-web.bnd.xml you need to specify which virtual host can display it. In this example App1 is specifying that it can only be viewed on "alice" virtual host.

Comment: Is there any way to do this on console? server.xml in my case is huge. Hundreds of lines!

Comment: Well, you can do it through the eclipse WAS plugin (server tab) (http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ibm-websphere-application-server-v85-developer-tools#.VCwj1_ldXww). However I'm not sure why opening an xml file with hundreds of lines would be an issue in notepads++ or any other basic editor. I played with files that has thousands of line and still worked fine.

Comment: Sorry... I meant its a complicated file and I'm scared to edit it manually.

Comment: Sure, the GUI plugin I posted its link in the previous comment can give you a friendlier environment. Be sure to get the right version for your eclipse and WAS.

Answer (score 0):

After some analysis I came to the below conclusion.

1. Each application server in WAS listens only on one port per
   protocol.
2. In WAS 8 ND, there is an option to create multiple application
   servers. (In the application servers tab, the 'New...' option is
   available only in WAS ND).
3. In WAS 8 Standalone server, the option to have multiple application
   servers is not available.
4. There seems to be a way to use transport chains to make the server
   listen to same protocol on another port as well, but the purpose is
   not to make one webapp available on each port. The purpose is to
   just route a secondary port to the base port for that protocol.
5. Even in WAS 8 standalone, there seem to be some scripting hack that
   can allow another server to be created. But I am not sure if license
   supports such usage.
6. Finally, the way to make two different applications on a single WAS
   8 standalone server available on different ports is to route the
   requests through two Web servers (reverse-proxy servers) (one per
   web application), and connect those web servers to WAS through WAS
   Web server plugins.
7. It is after the proxy routing that virtual hosts can be used to
   filter which reverse-proxy can communicate with which web
   application.

**To sum it up:**

In case of WAS 8 standalone,  web servers need to be used as reverse proxies. Forwarded requests from those reverse proxies can be filtered in WAS so that specific webapps are mapped to specific virtual hosts.