# Websphere Virtual Host

Tags: java, web-applications, websphere, port, web-deployment

IBM WAS 8 gives option to create virtual hosts.
At the time of WAR deployment, I am able to map the application to a particular virtual host.
For each virtual host, I am able to assign a port number (There is no protocol defined for the virtual host port - so, will it apply for HTTP?).

However, the application is not accessible using that port number.
Neither is the application accessible on the normal HTTP port of the server.

What is the gap here? Server doesn't listen on ports defined for virtual hosts other than default_host? Is a separate Http server required to listen on that port and forward the request to WAS?

Comment: Got the answer for my other question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26143263/how-to-set-ibm-websphere-8-to-serve-web-applications-on-different-ports

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you want to achieve.

If you want to connect directly to WebSphere but *via different ports*, then:

- you need to create new transport chains with new ports (via `Web container settings > Web container transport chains`)
- create new virtual host with alias mapped to that port (e.g. `*:port`)
- map your app during deployment to that port
- restart server (server will listen on this new port also)

If you want to connect directly to WebSphere, but *via different names*, then:

- you need to define host aliases for the server via /etc/hosts or dns, so for example hosts: app1.corp.com and app2.corp.com points to IP of your server.
- then change the default_host aliases from *:9080 to app1.corp.com:9080
- create second alias  app2_host, and define app2.corp.com:9080 alias
- map applications and restart server

If you want to connect to WebSphere *via http server* (e.g. IHS or Apache), then:

- you need to configure your http server, with plugin
- either listen on many ports e.g. 80  and 81, or create host aliases for your http server
- configure virtual hosts on WebSphere, to match either *:port or virtualname:80 (in this case port must be listening on the http server, not on the WebSphere server)
- map applications and restart server